# Python - Why is this happening?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python, and noticed something I believe its a bug.

Edit 2011-09-30:
Forget it. Now I know the attributes created are static and shared between the instances.
Hope this thread helps another python newbies in the same situation as mine.

Consider the following code:

```
class test():

    dictionary1 = {}
    list1 = []

    def method1(self):
        self.dictionary1.update({'1': 'unique entry'})
        self.list1 = ['unique list entry']

t=test()

print 'dictionary1 value:', t.dictionary1
print 'list1 value:', t.list1
t.method1()
print 'dictionary1 new value:', t.dictionary1
print 'list1 new value:', t.list1

t2=test()
print 'dictionary1 value:', t2.dictionary1, " -- error -- I just instantiated the class. The correct value would be {}"
print 'list1 value:', t.list1
t2.method1()
print 'dictionary1 new value:', t.dictionary1
print 'list1 new value:', t.list1
```

Now the question:

Why in line 19 the executed code shows:  `{'1': 'unique entry'}`. I belive it would be: `{}`
Note that the list has the correct value: `[]` (empty list in line 20)

```
Using Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
```

Sorry not so good english. From Brazil.

Edit 2011-09-30:
Forget it. Now I know the attributes created are static and shared between the instances.
Hope this thread helps another python newbies in the same situation as mine.

Comment: Rule no. 1: The bug is in your code or in your understanding of the feature, not in that mature, well-tested implementation.

Comment: Your code is totally broken. Post something that actually runs.

Comment: Is the indent for `self.list1 = ['unique list entry']` correct? It looks like it isn't inside `method1`.

Comment: you *overwrite* the list, and update the existing dictionary. That's why you think the list is unchanged

Comment: It does what it should: you're using a [static class variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python/68672#68672).

Comment: The problem is not the "not so good english" but a significant lack of understanding object oriented programming in Python

Comment: And [the list behaves just like the dictionary](http://ideone.com/IG6AD)

Comment: @Tarmac - In clear English: Please don't say you've found a bug unless you're *absolutely sure* it's not your fault. People get annoyed if it looks like you're blaming others.

Comment: Please don't be mean with the OP, he did said he's new. Please do not bite the newcomers.

Comment: So sorry for thinking it was a bug. I just asked if it was a bug. Maybe my poor english made it unclear.

Comment: Now I understand I made a confusion just based on my other programing languages knowledge.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All your instances of `test` class share the same dictionary and list. The correct way to initialize the members would be:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionary1 = {}
        self.list1 = []
```

Attributes assigned directly in the class body will be evaluated once and then shared between all instances. Since the `__init__` method is run once per instance, a new list and dictionary will be created for each instance.

Comment: And they share them because what OP declared were class variables (similar to `static` members in other languages).

Answer (score 7):

Variables directly declared in the class body ([static class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)) are shared among all instances of the class. Therefore, it's not a good idea to change them.

Instead, initialize object member variables in the constructor:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionary1 = {}
    def method1(self):
        self.dictionary1.update({'1': 'unique entry'})
```

Answer (score 5):

To add to the other answers, the reason you see different behaviour for the `dict` and the `list` is: when you write `self.dictionary1.update({'1': 'unique entry'})`, you change the contents of `self.dictionary1`, but it's still the same `dict` object. When you write `self.list1 = ['unique list entry']`, you replace `self.list1` with a new `list` object. You would get the same behaviour as with the `dict` by doing: `self.list1.append('unique list entry')`.

Comment: `self.list1 = ...` isn't replacing anything, since there's nothing to replace,  the instances' `__dict__` does not have the key 'list1', it's just adding it.  It happens that the class's

Comment: Sorry; it's adding an attribute to the instance which hides the attribute of the class.